# NSUserDefaults - How should I fix this code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I'm trying to make some sort of setup wizard that remembers a specific view however I have some problems with my AppDelegate.m code since I'm using ARC.
Does anyone know how to fix this, because If I compile the app crashes at the splash screen..

My AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSString *controllerName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"WIZARD_VIEW"];
    if ([controllerName length]) {
        Class controllerClass = NSClassFromString(controllerName);
        UIViewController *controller = [[controllerClass alloc] init];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
    }
```

To be more clear, in the viewcontroller files I added the following code as a suggestion:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[self class] description] forKey:@"WIZARD_VIEW"];
     NSLog(@"ViewWillAppear Done.");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"WIZARD_VIEW"];
     NSLog(@"viewWillDisappear");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Crashlog while compiling:

```
/Users/Tim/Documents/XCODE_DEV/App/AppDelegate.m:17:33: No visible @interface for 'NSUserDefaults' declares the selector 'forKey:'

/Users/Tim/Documents/XCODE_DEV/App/AppDelegate.m:20:27: Unused variable 'controller'
```

Comment: What is in your console/debugger at the time of the crash.

Comment: can you give us the error message please

Comment: Where do you register the defaults?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the crashlog at the bottom.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri in the view controller themself it's the second code.

Comment: That's not registering the defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you have to register the defaults.To register the defaults isn't enough to call the setObject:forKey method, you have to use the registerDefaults method:

```
- (void)registerDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

Documentation:
[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

So in your case:

```
NSUserDefaults* standard=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standard registerDefaults: @{ @"WIZARD_VIEW" : [[self class]description]} ];
```

You better place these lines in the initialize method, which gets called before any non-static method.If the defaults are already registred there's no problem, this will not overwrite the defaults that you have if is the 2nd+ time that the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the compiler warnings, I'm going to guess that in your AppDelegate.m, on line 17 you are calling `forKey:` on `NSUserDefaults`.

`NSUserDefaults` doesn't have a `forKey:` method, so it throws an exception.

It's probably just a square bracket in the wrong place.

Comment: AppDelegate.m:17:78: Use of undeclared identifier 'WIZARD_VIEW'
Sorry to ask this, but how should I fix these ?

Comment: No idea - I'm not psychic, you have to show me the code as well :) I guess that you've typed in `WIZARD_VIEW` without defining it as anything.

Comment: That's true should I change it to @"WIZARD_VIEW"

Comment: I'm _still_ not psychic - I have no idea what you're trying to do and what your code looks like! How can I possibly answer that question?